# rspec undefined local variable that have been `let`

Tags: ruby, rspec, let

I need to test if a file contains a certain list of words.

So I use let in a describe bloc :

```
let (:test_rb_structure) { %w(nom, description, prix, rdv, validation, heure, creation) }
```

And I call it like this in the same describe bloc :

```
describe 'in app/controllers/api/v1/comptes.rb' do
  subject { file('app/controllers/api/v1/comptes.rb') }
  it { is_expected.to exist }
  # Test structure is respected
  test_rb_structure.each do |structure|
    it { is_expected.to contain(structure) }
  end
end
```

I am having this error :

```
undefined local variable or method `test_rb_structure'
```

What is wrong ? I cannot figure out.

Comment: You referred to `test_rb_structure` outside an `it` block, where `let` variables are not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables defined using `let` are only available inside example (`it`) blocks. So you'd have to do something like the following:

```
describe 'in app/controllers/api/v1/comptes.rb' do
  let (:test_rb_structure) { %w(nom, description, prix, rdv, validation, heure, creation) }

  subject { file('app/controllers/api/v1/comptes.rb') }

  it { is_expected.to exist }

  it 'respects the test structure' do
    # Notice that `test_rb_structure` is used _inside_ the `it` block.
    test_rb_structure.each do |structure|
      expect(subject).to contain(structure)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, you have the benefit of using the `it` param be the description of your spec, versus doing it with a comment, which makes for much more readable specs in `rspec --format documentation`.